# Rails CarrierWave - able to save remote url image but unable to save local image file to database and AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

When I make a POST request to post a 'vision', it passes both required parameters correctly. However, when saved, the image column is left nil in the HEROKU database and it also does not upload in AWS S3.

How do I make it so that user can upload local files to aws and heroku?

**Vision table:**

```
class CreateVisions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :visions do |t|
      t.string :image
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**vision.rb**

```
class Vision < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

**visions_controller.rb create action:**

```
        def create
            @vision = current_user&.visions.build(vision_params)
            @vision.remote_image_url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png'

            @vision.save
            render :create, status: :created
        end
```

**I'm making my POST request like this (it works but the image column only saves when a remote URL is passed in the visions_controller.rb before save**

```
let response = await fetch('https://prana-app.herokuapp.com/v1/visions/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-User-Email': this.state.email,
                'X-User-Token': this.state.accessToken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              vision: {
                description: 'dsfsfdsfdsfsd',
                image: this.state.uploadFile
              }
            })
        });
```

**setup_fog.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] || '',
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] || '',  
      region: 'us-west-2'
    }

    config.fog_directory = 'BUCKET_NAME'
    config.fog_public = false
    config.fog_attributes = {
      'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"
    }
  end
```

**image_uploader.rb**

```
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  end

  version :thumb do
  process resize_to_fit: [64, 64]
end

version :small do
  process resize_to_fit: [200,200]
end

version :large do
  process resize_to_fit: [1000,1000]
end

version :medium  do
  process resize_to_fit: [400,400]
end

  def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

Comment: Heroku blocks you to write tempfiles in some cases. Did you get any error?

Comment: @FábioAraújo with my current code, I don't get any errors, because my code in the `visions_controller.` is overwriting the local file I've provided as the image parameter (`this.state.uploadFile`). However, when I remove the line `@vision.remote_image_url = 'https://www.xyz.png'`, I get ``` SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "visions" ("image", "description",xyz "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["image", nil], ["description", "xxx"], ["created_at", "2019-01-11 01:14:50.636458"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-11 01:14:50.636458"], ["user_id", 3]]```

Comment: remote_image_url retrieve the image from the link and save. As you say that CarrierWave only works when you add it, I made my way to think that is possible the this.state.uploadFile is empty or it's being a blocked param...

Comment: @FábioAraújo but even when I replace 'this.state.uploadFile' with a remote URL, the saving doesn't work as expected. It only ever works as long as I include this in my visions_controller: `@vision.remote_image_url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png'` before I save it. 
so in this ^ line of code, how can I replace the URL with the parameter I'm passing in my http request?  `@visions.remote_image_url = params[:image]` doesn't seem to work.

I tried `@visions.image = params[:image]` BUT that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I'm not sure but you can do `params[:image].path` or `params[:image][:tempfile]` something like this. Let me know the result.

Comment: @FábioAraújo doesn't seem to work